# How do I configure a Vagrant virtual machine with a host name?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-virtualhost, vagrant

I'm trying to use Vagrant to set up an Ubuntu/Apache virtual machine using Virtual Box on a Windows 10 host, and then configure my host machine so that opening the URL `magento.dev` in my browser pulls up a page on my virtual machine.

Here's the relevant configuration in my Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: 192.168.10.10
   config.vm.hostname = "magento.dev"
```

I added the line

```
192.168.10.10 magento.dev
```

to my `hosts` file in my Windows 10 host.

After provisioning my Vagrant machine, I removed the `.htaccess` file from my html directory to make sure that it's not doing something unexpected that's causing this problem.

I can open a browser and go to `http://192.168.10.10` on my Windows host, and the web page from the virtual machine is displayed.

I can `ping magento.dev` from my Windows host, and the ping shows an IP of `192.168.10.10` and returns a response.

However, if I go to `magento.dev` in my browser, I get a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error.  Also of note, the URL changes to `https`, whereas the `http://192.168.10.10` URL didn't change to `https`.

When I access `192.168.10.10` through the web browser on my Windows host, I can see the Apache access log get updated.  When I go to `magento.dev` in my browser, the Apache access log isn't updated.  So the Apache must ignoring my web request or not receiving it, but I can't figure out why because my Windows `hosts` file should be directing these requests to 192.168.10.10, which I can verify with the `ping magento.dev`.

How do I set this up so that going to `magento.dev` on my host machine returns the web page from my virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my previous answer, apparently I did not read your question before answering. This time I did, and luckily I know the actual answer :)

.dev is a registered TLD (top level domain), owned by Google. Chrome 63+ and Firefox 59+ will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.

Here is the whois data:

```
$ whois .dev
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

domain:       DEV

organisation: Charleston Road Registry Inc.
address:      1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
address:      Mountain View, CA 94043
address:      United States

contact:      administrative
name:         Domains Policy and Compliance
organisation: Google Inc.
address:      601 N. 34th Street
address:      Seattle, WA 98103
address:      United States
phone:        1 202 642 2325
fax-no:       1 650 492 5631
e-mail:       iana-contact@google.com

contact:      technical
name:         Richard Roberto
organisation: Google Inc.
address:      76 9th Avenue, 4th Floor
address:      New York, NY 10011
address:      United States
phone:        1 212 565 2633
fax-no:       1 650 492 5631
e-mail:       crr-tech@google.com

nserver:      NS-TLD1.CHARLESTONROADREGISTRY.COM 2001:4860:4802:32:0:0:0:69 216.239.32.105
nserver:      NS-TLD2.CHARLESTONROADREGISTRY.COM 2001:4860:4802:34:0:0:0:69 216.239.34.105
nserver:      NS-TLD3.CHARLESTONROADREGISTRY.COM 2001:4860:4802:36:0:0:0:69 216.239.36.105
nserver:      NS-TLD4.CHARLESTONROADREGISTRY.COM 2001:4860:4802:38:0:0:0:69 216.239.38.105
nserver:      NS-TLD5.CHARLESTONROADREGISTRY.COM 2001:4860:4805:0:0:0:0:69 216.239.60.105
ds-rdata:     60074 8 2 b942e2ce5aebf62fca59d05707e6dbb795211d540d8adba02e9e89e833424785

whois:        whois.nic.google

status:       ACTIVE
remarks:      Registration information: http://www.registry.google

created:      2014-11-20
changed:      2018-06-09
source:       IANA
```

Here is the relevant bit in the chromium source:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/63.0.3239.118/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json#255

```
// eTLDs
// At the moment, this only includes Google-owned gTLDs,
// but other gTLDs and eTLDs are welcome to preload if they are interested.
{ "name": "google", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https", "pins": "google" },
{ "name": "dev", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "foo", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "page", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "app", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "chrome", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
```

I advise you to use a different suffix. I tend to use an actual DNS record for one of my domains, but a .test suffix would work as well.

Comment: I did that.  My original question does say that I added `192.168.10.10 magento.dev` to my Windows 10 (host machine) `hosts` file.

Comment: Haha, whoops :)

Comment: There.. That fixed it :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was going crazy trying to figure this out.  I didn't realize that `.dev` is processed differently by the browser.  I changed it to `magento.local` and it worked.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for I can't remember how long. Big thank you!!!